# Oracle Veritas cluster failback to primary node while standby is up and running

Tags: oracle, jboss, cluster-computing

Have searched a lot for my question but seems like it's not something that is commonly used. The question here is around Oracle DB Veritas cluster that is based on 2 nodes, primary and stand-by.
The scenario is customer related and we are not touching it in case of good sense. All this stuff is running on **JBoss6.4** and intended to follow the logic below:

1. Application is connected to the Primary node(node1)
2. node1 goes down and application gets connected to the stand-by node(node2).
3. node2 is in Read-Only mode and by design node1 gets restarted and becomes reachable in 2 minutes.
4. While this outage an application has timeout before it starts sending heartbeat messages.
5. Once node1 is up and running the cluster should failback from node2 to node1 given that node2 is still running.

The question here is to get cluster failback to node1 even if node2 is running.
The connection string that is used:

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST =
>   (load_balance=off)(failover=on) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host =
>   node1) (Port = 49005)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host = node2)
>   (Port = 49005)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = app_service)))

Application is configured the way if it is not able to write heartbeat event to the database for 3 times, the JVM gets shutdown. Is there any ways to configure datasource connection so that it fails back to the primary node(node1) if it is available considering that node2 is up and running in RO mode?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a database for connecting a client using a special service name. For example, in the primary mode in the system trigger when the database starts.
You can dynamically redefine the service name by running the command

```
alter system set service_names='app_service_primary' scope=memory;
```

The trigger creates a service when the database starts in the primary mode. Clients are connected by the name of the service, which is created in the trigger at the start of the database, and not by the default database name or service.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sys.set_svc_name
 AFTER
  STARTUP
 ON DATABASE
DECLARE role VARCHAR(30);
BEGIN

SELECT Database_Role
INTO Role
FROM V$database;
IF Role = 'PRIMARY' THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system set service_names=''app_service_primary'' scope=memory'; END IF;

END;
```

need change connection string

```
  jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (load_balance=off)
(failover=on) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host = node1) (Port = 49005)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host = node2) (Port = 49005)) ) 
(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = app_service_primary)))
```